# Вернуть "консоль", где запускался проект на NextJS через npm start

Tags: nginx, сервер, frontend, npm, next.js

Возникла проблема, был запущен проект на  NextJS через `npm start` в **Терминале 1**, затем был создан новый **Терминал 2**(все действия происходят в VS code), где мы имеем возможность взаимодействовать с ней, например, выполнить команду `npm run dev`. При попытке выполнить команду `npm start` в **Терминале 2** получаем ожидаемую ошибку, что порт занят. Собственно сам вопрос: Можно ли "скопировать""открыть""любой другой термин" **Терминал 1** в **Терминале 2**, т.е. чтобы в **Терминале 2** была та же "картинка"

```
> test-2@0.1.0 start
> next start

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
(node:21752) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:22288) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

, что и в **Терминале 1**, чтобы можно было "завершить" проект через ctrl+c в **Терминале 2**, не влезая в **Терминал 1**. При условии, что нет возможности открыть **Терминал 1** и оттуда завершить через ctrl+c.

Пояснение, зачем это нужно: есть приложение, которое находится на сервере Digitalocean, к которому подключаешь через ssh. Там изначально уже была выполнена команда `npm start` (сайт работает и на него можно зайти), но нет той "картинки", которая видна после выполнения этой команды, вместо этого "Порт уже используется". Есть ещё pm2 там и там 2 процесса, но они не отвечают за этот проект на Next. Пробовал перезапускать/стопать-запускать nginx через restart\reload\stop-start. Нужно это для того, чтобы применились изменения(добавленные новые картинки, например, изменения в коде и т.д.), просто `npm run build` не достаточно, нужно именно сделать перезапуск "npm start"

Comment: Есть предположение, убить через `kill` процессы, найденные с помощью `sudo lsof -i :3000` (локальный эксперимент на windows и с использованием `taskkill` помог завершить процесс и можно было запустить заново `npm start` в **Терминале 2**). Пока это единственное решение. Может у кого-то будет другое

Comment: Нашел решение благодаря файлику **.bash_history**, который был в одном очень далеком месте, в котором сохранились команды из консоли предыдущих разрабов. Решение: в **Терминал** вводится команды `tmux a`, в открывшемся окне и были "те сообщения о запуске проекта через `npm start`". Дальше по-дефолту **ctrl+c** и `npm start`. После чего можно "удалить" (закрыть) терминал